# In how many ways can I partition a partition?

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

Let $\mathbf{k}= \langle k_1,...,k_u \rangle$ denote cardinalities of $\sum_{i=1}^{u}k_i = n$ objects, where $k_i$ is the cardinality of the $i^{th}$ object. In how many ways can I partition this partition into two new partitions $\mathbf{k'}= \langle k'_1,...,k'_u \rangle$ and $\mathbf{k''}= \langle k''_1,...,k''_u \rangle$, such that $\sum_{i=1}^{u}k'_i = m$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{u}k''_i = n-m$. Can I have something more informative than the solutions of the following equations:

$$\forall i. k'_i + k''_i = k_i$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{u}k'_i = m$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{u}k''_i = n-m$$
$$\sum_{i}^{u}k_i = n$$

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle` instead of `<` and `>` to get proper angled brackets with proper spacing.

Comment: If $m$ is not fixed, you just have to choose a number in between $0$ and $k_i$ for all $i\leq u$, so you will get $(k_1+1)(k_2+1)\cdots (k_u+1)$ partitions.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, it is essentially computing partitions of an integer into a fixed number of positive integers, each with an individual upper bound. Without those individual bounds, this problem is in the existing literature, see, e.g., https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X1500236X